# Expected number of random sub-cliques neccessary to cover a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value, coupon-collector

I have the following problem:

> Given a complete, simple graph, i.e., a graph $(V,E)$ where
>   every possible edge is realized, so $|E| = \frac{|V||V-1|}2$. Now
>   consider complete sub-graphs, or sub-cliques, of size $k$ be chosen at
>   random. Every times a sub-clique $(V',E')$ is chosen, the edges $E'\subseteq E$ are colored. How long does it take in expectation until every edge in
>   $E$ is colored?

I have searched for this problem, but not found anything.
Was this discussed before or does this problem even have a name?
For the case of $k=2$ it can be seen as the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) with $|E|$ coupons, but for bigger $k$ I found nothing.

PS: I am not asking for a solution, only for a direction, if there is a published solution ;)

Comment: Asked again six years later https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240216/suppose-we-have-n-people-a-random-selection-of-k-of-these-people-meet-each